# Why can't I open mathematica notebook using terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, mathematica

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have mathematica installed in my desktop. I know that if I type mathematica in terminal, it should open a notebook. But it is not doing that. Any solution to this??

Comment: Please describe what error you get.

Comment: Right click on the desktop icon, and select properties at the bottom of the list.  Look at the "Command" line, and type that into your terminal (may set env variables before running mathematica). Does that work?